# centering inputs in middle of a div

Tags: css, html, center

I want to both horizontally and vertically center a pair of inputs as part of a form to appear in the middle of a div. How do I go about properly doing this? I can only get them to be horizontally centered right now.

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id='flightdates'>
        <div id='wrapper'>
            <form id='dates'>Departing:
                <input type='text' id='departing'>
                <br/>Returning:
                <input type='text' id='returning'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#flightdates {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Looks centered to me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yYz6C/

Comment: I'm with @j08691, it looks centered.

Comment: I also want it centered vertically as in the middle of the rectangle yellow div, not just on top centered.

Comment: Check this out: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: @user3558649 - The you need to *say* that somewhere.

Comment: @John Bupit, Thanks for this resource! I'm new and this helps me to wrap my head around these concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They look horizontally centered - but if you're looking to also center them vertically, just add a single CSS definition:

```
#dates{
    line-height:50px;
}
```

Where `line-height` matches the height of `#flightdates`. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYz6C/2/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank-you! This was the desired result. Since I'm just learning, could you explain why I couldn't just add this to #wrapper or #flightdates?

Comment: Great, glad I could help out! Actually, you could add the same style to those elements as well to achieve the same effect, since the `line-height` style is passed from parent to child elements - so it would eventually be applied to `#dates`. But since `#dates` is the only element that actually needs this `line-height` to achieve the vertical centering, I thought it would be best to only apply the style to it.

Comment: The solution would only work if the content fits a single line. But, I guess, that suffices in this case.

Comment: Regrettably, you're right. For a more flexible solution, you might want to actually use `display:table-cell` and related styles. There's a detailed explanation here: http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/. I just wanted to achieve the effect with as little modification to the CSS as possible.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.className{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
```

As per comment.
The idea here is that the position must be set to absolute in order for the left and top to react properly.
The percentage is actually NOT as simple as it seems.  It doesn't take into account the width or height of the string that it's positioning.  So it may still seem ot of place.  You may have to tweek it a little.

Comment: When posting, please try to avoid code-only answers. Instead, add some details as to *why*  your answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<br/>` after the first input

Check the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/t6LWR/

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ua4E/)

Use display:table & table-cell to create a table like layout. which support vertical align middle.

Here is the CSS:

```
#flightdates {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height:50px;` to `#wrapper`

```
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle edxample](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yYz6C/3/)**

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you want to center the form both **horizontally AND vertically**, you can use the CSS transform trick:

```
#flightdates {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/yYz6C/1/

In fact, the `#wrapper` is not necessary. You can take it out, and apply the style to the form element, too.

Comment: very weird way of dealing with such a small problem 0_x

Comment: @ImranBughio Funny because you are mad that there are other solutions to your table-cell method? Please grow up. It has also been suggested elsewhere: http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/, http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ and http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center

Comment: @ImranBughio Downvoting other answers simply because they provide an alternative solution, without providing any constructive criticism, is a very juvenile behavior.

Comment: Sorry, Those are some authentic sources :) i take my down-vote back.

Comment: I still think this approach is a little werid cuz of the absolute position and negative transform

Comment: i can not take back my devote unless you edit some thing any thing in your answer

Comment: @ImranBughio I'm disappointed that despite receiving a university education you are still so closed minded and judgmental. I don't need to edit my answer to get that downvote away. I'll let it stay, as a hallmark on how jumping to conclusions quickly can be a very stupid thing to do. Over and out.